# Copy std::exception object to a struct member in C++

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>


enum class Severity
{
  TRACE,
  DEBUG,
  INFO,
  WARN,
  ERROR,
  FATAL,
};

struct LogRecord
{
  const Severity          mSeverity;
  const std::string       mTimestamp;
  const char* const       mFunc;
  const size_t            mLine;
  const char* const       mFile;
  std::string             mMessage;
  std::exception          mException;   


  LogRecord& operator<<(const std::exception& e)
  {
    mException = e;
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename T>
  LogRecord& operator<<(const T& msg)
  {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << msg;
    mMessage += ss.str();
    return *this;
  }
};


void throw_exception()
{
  throw std::logic_error("Logic error");
}
int main()
{
  LogRecord l{};
  try
  {
    throw_exception();
  }
  catch(std::exception& e)
  {
    l << "Test" << e;
    std::cout << l.mMessage << ": " << l.mException.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The main function prints "Test: std::exception" instead of "Test: Logic error". The reason is that "mException = e;" does not copy the exception to the mException member of my struct. What is the reason for that and how could I archieve that "Test: Logic error" is printed?

Comment: Looks like you dwelled into _implementation defined_ territory :( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/operator%3D

Comment: @YSC ok I see. Do you have any suggestion for a workaround to archieve what I want to do?

Comment: Are you maybe slicing the exception to the base type?

Comment: Isn't this just object slicing?

Comment: This is just object slicing; the type thrown exception is `std::logic_error`, but it's being copied into an object of type `std::exception`, so the `std::logic_error` part gets sliced off and all that's left is the `std::exception` part. This happens any time you copy a derived object into an object whose type is one of its bases.

Comment: Looks like what you really want is a [`std::exception_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr).  Since `std::exception mException;` will slice.

Comment: @Eljay but how can I use the "std::exception_ptr"? I think I can't access the what() method and I'm only able to rethrow the exception if I got it right?

Comment: @SimonRechermann -- look at the sample code in the link that Eljay gave you.

Comment: Reopened. Yes, the cause is object slicing, but that's not the end of the conversation. See the comment by @Eljay, which describes a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Would [`std::nested_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception) help?  _"...std::nested_exception is a polymorphic mixin class which can capture and store the current exception, making it possible to __nest exceptions of arbitrary types__ within each other...."_

Comment: something like this might be what you need? https://godbolt.org/z/zhcesjdMx

Comment: @RichardCritten -- not really; `std::nested_exception` is used when an outer layer of code needs to create a new exception object with a link to an earlier exception object, so that it can throw an exception of a domain-related type when it catches a lower-level exception, without losing the original exception information. This question is just about hanging on to the original exception object, without wrapping it in another exception. `std::exception_ptr` does seem like the right answer.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks! Instead of `std::current_exception()` I would like to use `std::make_exception_ptr(e)` https://godbolt.org/z/a8zfzjnTT why is this not working?

Comment: The linked duplicate is the right answer, but note that the accepted answer to that question (which insists that the only way to do this is to clone exception objects) is wrong.

Comment: @SimonRechermann -- Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. You've gotten a good answer (through the duplicate link) to your question. Now that you have a new problem, ask a new question!

Comment: See the note at the bottom of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/make_exception_ptr